# ActivityIndicatorView in nav bar continues animating after ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an issue with the activity indicator view continuing to animate after the page has finished loading. The problem only occurs on UIWebView pages that have already been visited.

I am also using MBProgressHUD and this stops animating after the ViewDidLoad as expected.

The page loads almost instantaniously and then the animation starts in the nav bar. It's almost as if the page is pulled from the device cache and then the application looks to go and load it.

The spinner only stops animating when you visit a different view controller.

Has anyone else faced issues similar to this?

**EDIT**

```
- (void)showNetworkActivity {
    [self performSelector:@selector(showNetworkActivityWithDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

- (void)showNetworkActivityWithDelay {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}

- (void)hideNetworkActivity {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

}
```

Works okay when I remove the delay.

I inherited the code, so I'm not sure whether the delay is needed. Is there any good reason to have a delay on showing the networkActivityIndicator?

Comment: Could you provide some code? thank you

Comment: Where do you call showNetworkActivity? I think delay it's not needed.

Comment: On webViewDidStartLoad and hide on webViewDidFinishLoad. Doesn't seem to hide on webViews that have previously been loaded. The content on the webViews that have the problem is just static html, not sure whether this would make a difference or not.

Comment: maybe the problem is the delay. try to call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];` and `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];` directly. hope it helps.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted works fine without the delay. Can you think of any good reason to keep a delay. I can't. Just thought it must have been coded that way initially for a reason. Unfortunately I can't speak to the people who initially did the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution.

Try to call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];` `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];` directly.

> performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: schedules a timer on the same
>   thread to call the selector after the passed delay.

I don't see reasons to use the delay in this examples. In fact, if you use it, the selector `showNetworkActivityWithDelay` is called after a delay and you could not see it immediately on the screen.

Obviously you can continue to wrap the activity indicator logic with the previous methods like the following (but it's not necessary):

```
- (void)showNetworkActivity {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}

- (void)hideNetworkActivity {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have `UIWebViewDelegate` set up. Set the delegate in the header/implementation, then start animating the indicator in `UIWebViewDelegate` `webViewDidStartLoad`, then stop animating in `webViewDidFinishLoad` and `webViewDidFailLoadWithError`.

Comment: I think I've confused things a little as it's the networkActivityIndicator that's showing up and continuing to animate. It only happens when a page is reloaded after being displayed previously. My code is set-up how Dan H suggests.